# What means this dtd, should I need to create a element or not? (Jdom, Java)

Tags: java, xml, dtd, jdom

```
<!ELEMENT Studiengang (Name,Fachgruppe,Studienbereich)>
<!ELEMENT Fachgruppe (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Studienbereich (#PCDATA)>
```

Hi , i have this dtd and i wanted to translate that to jdom, my problem is, that Name has not a element in the dtd, but fachgruppe and studienbereich has one...? What i should now do?

Should I create a element for name?

I am not sure, because Fachgruppe and Studienbereich have both a Element in the dtdt, but name not... So its not really clear for my what I have now to do...

Comment: `translate that to jdom`, what means this ? You may have `<Studiengang><Name>Informatik</Name>...` and you are saying `Name has not a element` ?. Fachgruppe has a "Name" ? Where ? Not clear what you have and what you want. You should reword your question, show an example of XML and what code do you have so far.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I believe that DTD allows this: Name is mandatory and its content is unconstrained.

Comment: @MichaelKay - You're correct. From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#elemdecls) (1.1 but it's the same in 1.0): _At user option, an XML processor may issue a warning when a declaration mentions an element type for which no declaration is provided, but this is not an error._